# Отследить изменение размеров и положения окна

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Как можно на C# сделать так, чтобы форма меняла размеры в зависимости от размеров и положения стороннего окна, зная его hWnd? То есть нужно как-то создать событие, которое бы уведомляло об этом. Это возможно? Если нужно использовать хуки, то как такой хук на C# сделать?

Comment: Думаю, чтобы не городить огород, проще вызвать WinAPI-шную функцию GetWindowRect. Придется, конечно, писать занудные DllImport и т.п.

Comment: Как ширину/высоту узнать понятно. А как узнать, что стороннее окно изменило размеры? Вопрос именно в этом. Можно, наверно, по таймеру вызывать тот же GetWindowRect, но как-то это не очень...

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [CallWindowProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633571(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Окна чужой программы? Без влезания в глубокие кишки - никак. С чужим окном ИМХО проще и безопаснее таймером.

Answer (score 2):

В итоге сделал опираясь на следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplicationMy
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]        
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]        
        static extern IntPtr SetWinEventHook(uint eventMin, uint eventMax, IntPtr
           hmodWinEventProc, WinEventDelegate lpfnWinEventProc, uint idProcess,
           uint idThread, uint dwFlags);                

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWinEvent(IntPtr hWinEventHook);

        delegate void WinEventDelegate(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType,
                      IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime);

        const uint EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE = 0x800B;
        const uint WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0;

        static IntPtr myHandle;
        static WinEventDelegate procDelegate;
        static IntPtr hhook;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", "Безымянный — Блокнот");            
            if (myHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return;
            }

            procDelegate = new WinEventDelegate(WinEventProc);
            hhook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero,
                    procDelegate, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);

            MessageBox.Show("");

            UnhookWinEvent(hhook);
        }

        static void WinEventProc(IntPtr hWinEventHook, uint eventType, IntPtr hwnd, int idObject, int idChild, uint dwEventThread, uint dwmsEventTime)
        {            
            if (myHandle == hwnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```